# How do I access a Profile model insider users_controller in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to access "profiles" table from my Profile model which belongs_to :user "User model".

Firstly in my show action of the users_controller I'd like to grab data from the profiles table in order to show on the users profile page.

Secondly I'd like to make it possible for users to edit these things using a form. I know this is done in the update action? while edit action makes it possible to show a form on the edit view page..

Here is my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController



  def new
    @user = User.new 
    @title = "Practice"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])   
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save 
        @user.build_profile.save #same as Profile.new(:user_id => @user.id)
        login @user
        UserMailer.join_confirmation(@user).deliver
        format.js   { render :js => "window.location = '#{root_path}'" } 
        flash[:notice] = "Welcome!"
      else

        format.js   { render :form_errors }
      end
    end
  end

  def show

  end

  def update

  end

  def edit

  end



end
```

1) How would I access my profiles table?
The User has_one :profile
The Profile belongs_to :user

Advice will be appreciated. Took me half of the day to figure out how to have a row corresponding to a newly created user at sign up created in the profiles table and now the next step is to be able to grab data from the model in my users_controller.  i know I could just create a profiles_controller and do things there but I don't want to attempt that right now as I'm sure there's a way to do it via the users_controller.

Thanks in advance for advice given.

View:

```
<%= @profile_data.first_name %>

<h4><%= current_user.username.capitalize %></h4>
<%= gravatar_image_tag(current_user.email, :alt => @title, :class => "gravatar", :gravatar => { :size => 150 }) %>
<br />
```

Trying to pull first_name from profiles table through users_controller

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    @profile_data = @user.profile

  end
```

route:

```
  match ':username' => "users#show"
```

I expect to see the name stored in first_name column of the profiles table when i visit localhost:3000/username

it doesn't show the users first name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
@user.profile
```

That will return the profile belonging to the User

Otherwise:

```
Profile.where('whatever condition you fancy')
```

will return A profile object based on conditions

Comment: i get this error: undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass

Comment: That means that user is empty. You'll need to populate it. Probably using something like: @user = User.find(params[:id]) but couldn't tell you more without seeing routes and what action you're running

Comment: I have some data in the profiles table. I have a users profile at localhost:3000/username and here is the route for that "match ':username' => "users#show"" now what I want to do is have data for that user show on the users page when I visit it. So in the show view I have @variable_set_in_controller.first_name to see if it can grab the first name. In the show action I have tried everything and still no luck. I just want to be able to grab info from the profiles table/profile model into the show action of the users_controller

Comment: I the show action you need to set the `@user` so your show action would look something like `def show @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])     @profile = @user.profile` The routes shows that the parameter passed is the username, so you need to use this to find the user object

Comment: I added those things to my show action then tried to call from show view the age loads up but it doesn't pull the data. So in show i changed [at]profile.first_name to something else that I know doesn't exist. I get an error of undefined method so I set it back to [at]profile.first_name and error is fine so it seems to finding the data but for some reason it won't display it.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to show your controller (show action) your view code, what you expect to be happening and what is happening. Also, what an example data would be useful.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6464/discussion-between-gregoryhouse-and-yule)

Comment: It turns out I just needed to reset the rails server and it worked with @user.profile after.

Answer (score 0):

You want a [`has_one`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one)`:profile` on the User model, and a [`belongs_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)`:user` on the Profile model, making sure you have the appropriate `user_id` column in the profiles table. Add [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for)`:profile` to the User model and then you can create/edit the user's profile in the same form for editing users.

Read up on the rails [release notes on nested attributes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#nested-attributes) and guides: [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and [forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

Comment: no luck, I've tried using find by username in the show action but for some reason my logs are telling me it's finding "favicon" as the username. Makes no sense.